# C++ Template Arguments not working

Tags: c++

I have something similar to this,

```
class Image {
  template <typename T> using iterator = ImageIteratorBase<Image, T>;
};

template <typename ImageType>
class Filter {
  template <typename PixelType> apply();
};
```

In my `Filter::apply()` function, I need to do this:

```
template <typename ImageType>
template <typename PixelType>
void Filter<ImageType>::apply() {
    using IteratorType = typename ImageType::iterator<PixelType>;
}
```

But this does not work and yields the error

```
 error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

What is wrong in here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Missing a closing semicolon after `Filter` declaration?

Comment: Try `using IteratorType = typename ImageType::template iterator<PixelType>;`

Comment: @Oktalist that's it, thanks :)